# getView() is not called in custom list adapter?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is my `homepage.xml` - where list view is placed:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.andapps.azaz.e_recommender.HomePage">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Category:"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spcategorieshomepage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14sp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        >


   </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/llhome"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14sp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


        </ListView>



    </LinearLayout>







</LinearLayout>
```

And also my customlist.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product ID:"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:id="@+id/tvproductid"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product Name:"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:id="@+id/tvproductname"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product Rating:"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14sp"
        android:max="5"
        android:numStars="5" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:id="@+id/tvproductdesc"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14sp"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

My `homepage.java` contains code which is using `AsyncTask` to consume REST API and fill arrays of data and send it to `customAdapter.java`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);



        Bundle emailbundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        email=emailbundle.get("email").toString();
        initializer();

        addingItemstoSpinner();

    }


protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            len= jsonArray.length();
            pdLoading.dismiss();
            if (len != 0) {
                try {




                    String [] productIDListArr= new String[len];
                    String [] productNameListArr= new String[len];
                    String [] productDescListArr= new String[len];
                    String [] productImagesArr= new String[len];
                    String [] productStarsArr= new String[len];
                    for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
                    {
                        objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        productIDListArr[i]=(objectInArray.getString("productId"));
                        productNameListArr[i]=(objectInArray.getString("productName"));
                        productDescListArr[i]=(objectInArray.getString("stars"));
                        productImagesArr[i]=(objectInArray.getString("productId"));
                        productStarsArr[i]=(objectInArray.getString("stars")+" out of 5");




                        if(i==len-1)
                        {
                            createdAt=objectInArray.getString("createdAt");
                        }


                    }
                    lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(HomePage.this, productIDListArr,productNameListArr,productDescListArr,productImagesArr,productStarsArr,email));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server is down please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

**My customAdapter.java is**

```
package com.andapps.azaz.e_recommender;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

/**
 * Created by M.Azaz on 30-Mar-17.
 */
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String [] productIDListArr,productNameListArr,productDescListArr,productImagesArr,productStarsArr;
    Context context;
    String email;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public CustomAdapter(HomePage homePage, String[] productIDList, String[] productNameList, String[] productDescList, String[] productImages, String[] productStars,String emailMain) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        productIDListArr=productIDList;
        productNameListArr=productNameList;
        productDescListArr=productDescList;
        productImagesArr=productImages;
        productStarsArr=productStars;
        context=homePage;
        email=emailMain;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return productIDListArr.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return productIDListArr[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tvproductname, tvproductid, tvproductdesc;
        ImageView imageView;
        RatingBar ratingBar;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_list, null);
        holder.tvproductname=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvproductname);
        holder.tvproductid=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvproductid);
        holder.tvproductdesc=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvproductdesc);
        holder.imageView=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.ratingBar=(RatingBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

        holder.tvproductname.setText(productNameListArr[position]);
        holder.tvproductid.setText(productIDListArr[position]);
        holder.tvproductdesc.setText(productDescListArr[position]);
        holder.ratingBar.setRating(Integer.parseInt(productStarsArr[position]));
        Picasso.with(context).load(context.getString(R.string.imageip) + productImagesArr[position]+".jpg").into(holder.imageView);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+productIDListArr[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.andapps.azaz.e_recommender.RATINGS");
                intent.putExtra("tag",productIDListArr[position]);
                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

But when I run the code, it actually calls `customAdapter.java` but right after calling `getCount()` from `customAdapter` Its not calling `getView` and the application terminates.

One more thing... how can I update more items into existing list?

Comment: show your logcat

Comment: productIDListArr.length what it return?

Comment: it returns the length of array that in which data is actually placed

Comment: what does `CustomAdapter#getCount()` return?

Comment: size of array in which data is placed

Comment: i see it calls `return productIDListArr.length;`, the question is what value does `CustomAdapter#getCount()` return?

Comment: its returning 4 in my case

Comment: so `getCount` is called (returning value of 4) and after that `getView` is not called? i am assuming you added some `Log.d` calls or run your app in debug mode to double check that?

Comment: no error is displaying in debug mode but i double check my value of length its 4 in getCount method

Comment: was `getCount` called after calling `lv.setAdapter(..)`? did you use `Log.d` to log the value `getCount` returns?

Comment: Bunlde of thanks all of you i just found my error :). Cheers

Comment: so what was it?

Comment: parsing data error I was sending string and trying to manipulate as integer in getView but unfortunately android studio 2.3 has some bugs no error was showing in loncat and debug window

Comment: then `getView` was indeed called ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You app may crash in getCount method when productIDListArr is null. So add if condition in your getCount method before returning count.

For example :

```
  public int getCount(){
    if(productIDListArr==null){
     return 0;
     }else{
     return  productIDListArr.length;
      }
   }
```

Tips : Create a class for holding your response data and pass the list of that model class to the adapter and each time when there is any change in your data update that list and call notify method of adapter.

For example :

```
     Class Item{
            public String productIDListArr;
            public String productNameListArr;
            public String productDescListArr;
            public String productImagesArr;
            public String productStarsArr;
         }

   ArrayList<Item> items=new ArrayList<Item>();
     for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
       {
        objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Item item=new Item();
        item.productIDListArr=(objectInArray.getString("productId"));
        .......
       }

CustomAdapter extend BaseAdapter{
ArrayList<Item> items;
public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<Item> items){
 this.items=items;
 }     
public int getCount(){
return items==null?0:items.size()
}
```

Comment: thats not a problem i have already posted a check if data is null its not calling customAdapter class